# How can I count the number of columns on a given condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a following query that results in the following output:

```
select file_name, 
       count(account_number) as account_count
  from tbl_account_detail 
 group by file_name;

-------------------------------------------------------
        FILE_NAME       |  CUR_DATE   |  ACCOUNT_COUNT
-------------------------------------------------------
 20151124_99999_101.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     499
 20151124_99999_102.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     500
 20151124_99999_103.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     500
 20151124_99999_104.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     499
 20151124_99999_105.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     500
 20151124_99999_107.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     500
```

But I want to count the account on the basis of a column history_flag that has values 0, 1, 2 and group by that too and result should be like

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         FILE_NAME      |  CUR_DATE   | P_account(0) | H_account(1) | h1_account(2)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 20151124_99999_101.xml |  05-DEC-15  |     400      |      50      |      20
 20151124_99999_102.xml |  05-DEC-15  |      50      |     300      |     100
 20151124_99999_103.xml |  05-DEC-15  |      50      |     200      |     100
 20151124_99999_104.xml |  05-DEC-15  |      49      |     100      |     100
 20151124_99999_105.xml |  05-DEC-15  |      50      |     100      |     100
 20151124_99999_107.xml |  05-DEC-15  |      50      |     100      |     100
```

Because the accounts have a flag that decides whether it is a production or history account. How can I achieve this `count(account_number) as p_account(0), count(account_number) as H1_account(1), count(account_number) as H2_account_number` something like that?

**Contents of TBL_ACCOUNT_DETAIL:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER  |          FILE_NAME       |  HISTORY_FLAG
------------------------------------------------------------
 00011140107315  |  20151124_99999_104.xml  |       0
 00011140104490  |  20151124_99999_104.xml  |       1
 00011140108151  |  20151124_99999_104.xml  |       0
 00011140108161  |  20151124_99999_104.xml  |       0
 00532050000039  |  20130605_99999_233.xml  |       0
```

Comment: Something wrong with your SELECT. Please edit.

Comment: @jarlh sorry forgot that.:)done

Comment: Can you add some sample table data too, including column names?

Comment: `How can I achieve this..` by using [case expression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) or [pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) clause (Oracle 11g and up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select file_name,
       count(account_number) as account_count,
       sum(case when history_flag = 0 then 1 end) as hist_0,
       sum(case when history_flag = 1 then 1 end) as hist_1,
       sum(case when history_flag = 2 then 1 end) as hist_2
from tbl_account_detail 
group by file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select distinct file_name, count(1) over (partition by file_name) as account_count,
count(1) over (partition by <second_column>) as <second_alias>
from tbl_account_detail;
```

It is called as analytic functions and you can apply many aggregate functions such as rank(), row_number(), sum(), min(), max(), avg() etc.